# Remove unwanted additional space around SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I use sprite SVG, everything is ok until I add `width` and `height` to my SVG.

But when I add some `width` and `height`, additional space appears.
[image]

Here is HTML code:

```
<svg>
<use href="https://example.com/sprite-svg.svg#moneyback-icon"</use>
</svg>
```

And SVG:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" id="moneyback-icon">
<path fill="#E69329" d="M249.6 460.8 358.4 672l202.7-83.2 93.8-271L339.2 335z"></path>
<path fill="#546E7A" d="M153.6 768a166.4 166.4 0 1 0 332.8 0 166.4 166.4 0 1 0-332.8 0Z"></path>
<path fill="#90A4AE" d="M320 576c-106.7 0-192 85.3-192 192s85.3 192 192 192 192-85.3 192-192-85.3-192-192-192zm0 341.3c-83.2 0-149.3-66.1-149.3-149.3S236.8 618.7 320 618.7 469.3 684.8 469.3 768 403.2 917.3 320 917.3z"></path>
<path fill="#90A4AE" d="M298.7 704h42.6v170.7h-42.6z"></path>
<path fill="#FFB74D" d="M275.2 768c21.3 40.5 68.3 57.6 108.8 36.3l352-181.4a127 127 0 0 0 47-40.5c36.2-68.3 119.4-228.3 174.9-367L569.6 401.2 467.2 554.7l-145 76.8c-55.5 27.7-72.6 89.6-47 136.5z"></path>
<path fill="#FFB74D" d="m644.3 64-352 134.4c-15 4.3-32 21.3-47 36.3L126 394.7a116 116 0 0 0-10.7 108.8c8.5 21.3 36.3 72.5 66.1 130.1A188 188 0 0 1 320 576c8.5 0 19.2 0 27.7 2.1L303 488.5l98.2-87.4h170.6S902.4 354 960 215.5L644.3 64z"></path>
<path fill="#FFCDD2" d="M388.3 768a51.6 51.6 0 0 1-70.4-27.7 51.6 51.6 0 0 1 27.7-70.4c25.6-12.8 68.3 85.3 42.7 98.1z"></path>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use a viewBox like the one you have for the symbol: `<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><use...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size 300x150 that you can see in the dev tools is the default size of an SVG, where no width, height or viewBox attribute has been defined. Give the SVG a viewBox attribute. The numbers are not important as long as if fits the aspect ratio of the content (in this case the `<use>` element that refers to a `<symbol>` elements that has a viewBox 1024 wide and 1024 high). Now (after defining the viewBox) you can remove the width and height attributes of the `<symbol>` element. They will just confuse stuff. And then let the CSS control the width and height of the SVG (here width of 120px) either directly on the SVG or on a parent HTML element.

```css
svg.icon {
  border: thin solid red;
  width: 120px;
}

svg.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use href="#moneyback-icon"/>
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" id="moneyback-icon">
    <path fill="#E69329" d="M249.6 460.8 358.4 672l202.7-83.2 93.8-271L339.2 335z"></path>
    <path fill="#546E7A" d="M153.6 768a166.4 166.4 0 1 0 332.8 0 166.4 166.4 0 1 0-332.8 0Z"></path>
    <path fill="#90A4AE" d="M320 576c-106.7 0-192 85.3-192 192s85.3 192 192 192 192-85.3 192-192-85.3-192-192-192zm0 341.3c-83.2 0-149.3-66.1-149.3-149.3S236.8 618.7 320 618.7 469.3 684.8 469.3 768 403.2 917.3 320 917.3z"></path>
    <path fill="#90A4AE" d="M298.7 704h42.6v170.7h-42.6z"></path>
    <path fill="#FFB74D" d="M275.2 768c21.3 40.5 68.3 57.6 108.8 36.3l352-181.4a127 127 0 0 0 47-40.5c36.2-68.3 119.4-228.3 174.9-367L569.6 401.2 467.2 554.7l-145 76.8c-55.5 27.7-72.6 89.6-47 136.5z"></path>
    <path fill="#FFB74D" d="m644.3 64-352 134.4c-15 4.3-32 21.3-47 36.3L126 394.7a116 116 0 0 0-10.7 108.8c8.5 21.3 36.3 72.5 66.1 130.1A188 188 0 0 1 320 576c8.5 0 19.2 0 27.7 2.1L303 488.5l98.2-87.4h170.6S902.4 354 960 215.5L644.3 64z"></path>
    <path fill="#FFCDD2" d="M388.3 768a51.6 51.6 0 0 1-70.4-27.7 51.6 51.6 0 0 1 27.7-70.4c25.6-12.8 68.3 85.3 42.7 98.1z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: I followed your code but the final output is a very big image! I need smaller svg

Comment: @Amin you should set the width/height using CSS on the SVG element that has the class name "icon". Like in my example where it says 120px.